# Is IIS built on top of httplistener?

Tags: asp.net, iis, httplistener

Come on, I just suddenly wondered. Don't you wonder things too?

Note that I'm quite clear already that for any IIS before IIS6, the answer will be no. I suspect the answer is no for any other IIS too, but I'm looking for someone who *knows* this stuff. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well `HttpListener` uses a kernel module called http.sys under the hood which is what IIS uses as well. http.sys is responsible for listening for inbound HTTP connections and routing them to the appropriate listening application.

When you use `HttpListener` from code you configure a listener prefix which is used to register your application's listener with http.sys. IIS does a similar thing...

There's a fair bit of detail on the subject [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture).